# How to remove sour taste from curry?

Tags: yogurt, curry

My curry become too pulupu (sour)  due to too much yogurt. There is too  much sour taste in each bite. Now how can i remove sour taste from curry?

Comment: Your question is rather similar to the one asked about an hour before : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/93503/67

Answer (score 1):

Butter is the opposite of acidic/sour so adding butter can help balance the dish and remove the taste of sour.

Comment: Butter = fat basic taste, with a bit of sweet basic taste.